# How to apply (:thumb) using carrier wave in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I add a `:thumb` version, the image gets broken.

This is my view code:

```
<%= link_to image_tag(reg.orglogo.url(:thumb)) %>
```

And this is my `uploader.rb`:

```
class OrgimgUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  process resize_to_limit: [200, 200]
  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fill => [100, 100]
  end
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I probably think the reason behind the images being broken is that the images uploaded already are not affected by the `Thumb` version. So edit the image or re-add a image.

Then this should work for you :

```
<%= link_to image_tag(reg.orglogo.url(:thumb).to_s) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

**UPDATE**

```
<%= image_tag(reg.orglogo.thumb.orglogo_url) %>
```